# Can a Waterline model access its collection in life-cycle events?

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I have a model where only one record can have a 'current' property set to, for example, 1.

Is it possible for the `beforeCreate` or `beforeUpdate` to access the collection. Basically I want to do something like this:

```
afterUpdate: function (values, next) {
    // If this value is current, reset all the others
    if (values.current == 1) {
        this.collection.update({
            id: { '!': values.id }
        }, {
            current: 0
        }, next);
    }
}
```

What id don't know is what I can reliably use for `this.collection` in the example above.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you're using Sails v0.10.X you can access any model using sails global variable:

```
sails.models.users.find({id: 1})
```

*Note: all model names in sails.models are in lower case*

Comment: I'm not using sails. I'm using Waterline standalone. I guess I could use a factory pattern to put the Waterline object in the scope of the model, but I'd prefer to avoid that. It does seem reasonable that `this` of the event handlers should be the model (it appears to be the global context).